# Where should I ask a question about a business?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where should I ask a question about a business?
I have a question about legal rights.

Comment: You need to be more specific than this to get an answer, several sites could apply

Comment: @enderland Edited my question

Comment: Please include the question you'd like to ask, as even "legal rights about business" is still too broad.

Comment: @AdamDavis When I accept international customers, would that cause a lot of trouble? With trouble I mean: would I have to take account of the rules of each country?

Comment: I think it may be a better idea to ask the question at the KvK Hallo! (forum of chamber of commerce in The Netherlands). Thanks for the responses though.

Answer (score 3):

If your question relates to specific legal rights, **NOT** the Workplace.

One of our close reasons is:

> Questions seeking advice on company-specific regulations, agreements, or policies should be directed to your manager or HR department. Questions that address only a specific company or position are of limited use to future visitors. Questions seeking legal advice should be directed to legal professionals. For more information, click here.

Comment: OK, thanks. Any advice on what site I _should_ place it? It's got nothing to do with company-specific regulations by the way.

Comment: @WilliamDavidEdwards I'm not sure. I mainly posted this because inevitably someone would have suggested it otherwise. If it primarily relates to startups you might try [here](http://www.brightjourney.com/) - this used to be Startups.SE but the beta failed and it got sent elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks. Is that website powered by SE?

Comment: >> Could not authenticate you from Facebook because "Invalid credentials". - Okay... nope.

Answer (score 2):

If you re-write it as though you are freelancing, you might be able to get good answers here:

https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/

It used to be that there was a site, onstartups.com, that would have worked well, but they diverged from stackexchange and I don't know that they're a good place for such advice anymore.

Answer (score 2):

You should ask a lawyer about anything legal. That being said, there is now a new [startups.stackexchange.com](https://startups.stackexchange.com/) where your questions might find a home.

<sub>*Startups is currently in private beta. It may or may not progress to a public site. However, you can join now by going to the [proposal on Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/62811/startups).*</sub>